# idea YAML files warning: Cannot resolve configuration property KEY

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Eclipse project moves to idea, it can run without any errors, but I found YAML files have warnings like that:

> Cannot resolve configuration property 'DingdingRobot.dingtalkRobotUrl'
>   less... (⌘F1)  Inspection info: Checks Spring Boot application .yaml
>   configuration files. Highlights unresolved and deprecated
>   configuration keys and invalid values

POM included spring-boot-configuration-processor:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

code snippet:

```
processor:
    executor:
      threadNumber: 600
      timeout: 37
```

The keys threadNumber and timeout have background warning color, moving the cursor over tips cannot resolve configuration property `'processor.executor.threadNumber'`.

Comment: Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204070. Add the YAML file to the Spring Context configuration manually: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#spring-file-set.

Answer (score 0):

Recently faced the same issue.

Taking your properites file as an example I solved it by rewriting properties in `application.properties` (or `application.yml`) from format:

```
processor:
  executor:
    threadNumber: 600
    timeout: 37
```

to full-name format for every property:

```
processor.executor.threadNumber: 600
processor.executor.timeout: 37
```

Worked on Mac with `Intellij Idea` 2020.3 and `Gradle` 5.6.4