# Warning "Cannot resolve configuration property X" with custom @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, yaml

How do I make these warnings go away?

[image]

```yaml
gateway:
  servers:
    - url: https://localhost:8080
      description: Dynamic-Gateway
  versionPrefix: /api/v1
  publicPatterns:
    - /api/v1/registration/**
    - /api/v1/login/**
    - /actuator/**
    - /swagger-ui/**
    - /webjars/**
    - /doc/*
  ignoredPatterns:
    - /error/**
```

The properties are accessed from my `@ConfigurationProperties` file fine, but those warnings just get on my nerves

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "gateway")
@Setter
public final class GatewayMeta {
    private List<Server> servers;
    private String versionPrefix;
    private String[] publicPatterns;
    private String[] ignoredPatterns;

    public List<Server> servers() {
        return this.servers;
    }

    public String versionPrefix() {
        return this.versionPrefix;
    }

    public String[] publicPatterns() {
        return this.publicPatterns;
    }

    public String[] ignoredPatterns() {
        return this.ignoredPatterns;
    }
}
```

Baeldung [suggested](https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-resolve-spring-boot-configuration-properties) adding this dependency

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

I added it, reloaded the project, nothing changed

Before you close it as a duplicate, I want you to know that I checked these five similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789896/idea-yaml-files-warning-cannot-resolve-configuration-property-key), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116758/how-do-i-resolve-spring-configuration-property-without-configurationproperties), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75570120/cannot-resolve-configuration-property-spring-test), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75539937/cannot-resolve-configuration-property-spring-cloud-gcp-credentials-location), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926463/cannot-resolve-configuration-property-spring-h2-console-enabled)

For the most part, they weren't answered, but one person [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66651537/23299948) switching to `properties`. I don't want to

One guy [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789896/idea-yaml-files-warning-cannot-resolve-configuration-property-key#comment98250864_55789896) in the comments that I should

> Add the YAML file to the Spring Context configuration manually

and linked [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#spring-file-set). It simply says to navigate to your installed pugins and ensure that all Spring-related ones are checked. They are

[image]

I can suppress, though. If I put it in my `yml`, the warnings go away. But it feels like a hack

```yaml
#file: noinspection SpringBootApplicationYaml
```

How am I supposed to avoid such warnings?

Java 17. Spring Boot 3.2.1. Ultimate IntelliJ 2022.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `servers()` to `getServers()` should nudge IntelliJ in the right direction.

See [Naming convention for getters/setters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948083/naming-convention-for-getters-setters-in-java) for more details on getters/setters conventions in Java (or JavaBeans to be more precise).

By the way, I see that you're using Lombok's `@Setter` - adding `@Getter` (either on class or on fields) should also resolve the error.